# How do i make another Api call onclick in vue js

Tags: javascript, api, vue.js

I am new to vue js and i have this component, i am trying to make another API call on click of one of the list options.

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <h1 class="text-center text-4xl font-bold">Our Product</h1>
    <ul class="flex items-center justify-center gap-5">
      <li class="cursor-pointer text-xl" @click="handleClick(1)">Clothes</li>
      <li class="cursor-pointer text-xl" @click="handleClick(5)">Shoes</li>
      <li class="cursor-pointer text-xl" @click="handleClick(2)">Watches</li>
      <li class="cursor-pointer text-xl" @click="handleClick(4)">Furniture</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="grid grid-cols-3 gap-5">
      <div v-for="store in stores" :key="store.category.id">
        <div class="max-w-xl h-auto">
          <img :src="store.images[0]" alt="img" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { computed, ref, watch } from "vue";

import Clothes from "../Products/Clothes.vue";
import Shoes from "../Products/Shoes.vue";
import axios from "axios";

export default {
  components: {
    Clothes,
    Shoes,
  },
  props: [],
  data() {
    return {
      stores: [],
      errors: [],
      product: ref(1), //Where product is the changeable value
    };
  },
  methods: {
    handleClick(params) {
      this.product = params;
      console.log(this.product);
    },
  },

//Here is the Api call.
  async created() {
    await axios
      .get(
        `https://api.escuelajs.co/api/v1/categories/${this.product}/products`
      )
      .then((res) => {
        this.stores = res.data;
        console.log(this.stores);
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log(this.errors.push(e));
      });
  },
```

I want that when i click for a particular product it changes to the number i inserted, Thanks

Answer (score 2):

1. Don't use `ref` when you use the option api, you're mixin up option api and composition api (the `setup` function)
2. Move your api call to a method and call it from both `created` and `handleClick`

```js
export default {
  components: {
    Clothes,
    Shoes,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      product: 1,
      stores: [],
      errors: [],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    fetchProduct(productId) {
      return axios.get(`https://api.escuelajs.co/api/v1/categories/${productId}/products`)
        .then((res) => {
          this.stores = res.data;
        })
        .catch((e) => {
          this.errors.push(e);
          console.error(e);
        });
    },
    handleClick(productId) {
      this.product = productId;
      this.fetchProduct(productId);
    },
  },

  //Here is the Api call.
  async created() {
    await this.fetchProduct(this.product);
  },
};
```

Comment: It's not working, There's no change when  i click on an item, Basically it doesn't make the call

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait for sync call :

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      product: 1,
      stores: [],
      errors: [],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    async fetchProduct(productId) {
      await axios.get(`https://api.escuelajs.co/api/v1/categories/${productId}/products`)
        .then((res) => {
          this.stores = res.data;
        })
        .catch((e) => {
          this.errors.push(e);
          console.error(e);
        });
    },
    handleClick(productId) {
      this.product = productId;
      this.fetchProduct(productId);
    },
  },
  async created() {
    await this.fetchProduct(this.product);
  },
})
app.mount('#demo')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/1.2.2/axios.min.js" integrity="sha512-QTnb9BQkG4fBYIt9JGvYmxPpd6TBeKp6lsUrtiVQsrJ9sb33Bn9s0wMQO9qVBFbPX3xHRAsBHvXlcsrnJjExjg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <button @click="handleClick(3)">get productid 3</button>
  {{stores}}
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you soo much, Worked like magic, what was left was this.fetchProduct(productId) in the handleClick function